# Wordpress Contact form 7 ошибка

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

У меня следующая проблема. Локально форма cf7 успешно отправлялась через smtp. А на тестовом сервере форма выдает красную ошибку:
`"There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."`
При этом SMTP работает, и тестовое письмо из админки мне приходит, ошибок нет. В консоли тоже тишина. Может кто то сталкивался с подобным и может помочь с решением?
П.С проблема была не только в этом. Еще была ошибка `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` в консоли при попытке отправить ajax запрос. Не грузился файл admin-ajax.php. Исправил кодом:

```
add_filter('allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins');

function add_allowed_origins($origins) {
   $origins[] = 'http://мой-домен.ххх';
   return $origins;
}
```

И есть подозрение, что это может быть как то связано

Comment: При правильно перенесенном сайте вот этот код с allow_http_origins не нужен вообще. Как переносили на сервер?

Comment: В общем, если перенесли не с помощью плагина Duplicator, сносите на сервере и переносите по новой.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась совсем в другом:) В настройках формы, среди заголовков, поле From, там мне потребовалось указать ту почту, которая указана в настройках smtp. Тогда письма начали отправляться без проблем.
На счет allow_http_origins, да, там я ошибся, этот код действительно не нужен.